# Failed to initialize Amplify with PluginError: Unable to decode configuration

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify

Whenever im trying to upload an image, app crashes, after investigating the issue, I reached the following:
when calling Amplify.configure, its failing and im getting the following error:

```
Failed to initialize Amplify with PluginError: Unable to decode configuration
Recovery suggestion: Make sure the plugin configuration is JSONValue.
```

the upload code where the app is crashing is as follow:

```
     Amplify.Storage.uploadData(key: String(actualKey), data: data) { (event) in 
..... }
```

my code is as following in app delegate:

```
private func setupAWS() {
    do {
        let storafePlugin = AWSS3StoragePlugin()
        try Amplify.add(plugin: storafePlugin)
        try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
        try Amplify.configure()
        print("Amplify configured with storage plugin")
    } catch {
        print("Failed to initialize Amplify with \(error)")
    }
}
```

the amplify json file is as follow:

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "storage": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsS3StoragePlugin": {
                "bucket": "xxxxxx",
                "region": "eu-central-1",
                "defaultAccessLevel": "guest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

anyone knows what's going around?
thanks

**UPDATE:** when I remove the following:

```
try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
```

the error disappears, but on image upload im getting a new error:

```
Fatal error: No plugins added to Authentication category.
```

Comment: What amplify version you are using?

Comment: amplify version is 1.0

Comment: The error is similar to ones I've gotten where my amplifyconfiguration.json had a syntax error.  I've dropped the json you provided into a validator and the syntax checks out, but I still feel like that is where the error lies.  Double-check all the values in the syntax and make sure everything is configured to the same amplify version.  I've only used amplify v2.0 myself.

Comment: what validator and syntax checks out? 
can you show me an example?
@Substance586